# Bouncing ball 5 times jquery/javascript beginners level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am quite new to js and jQuery and wanted to achieve a simple animation that has been discussed many times here: a bouncing ball. However, I did not find the answer to my specific question as topics discussed already were much more sophisticated.

I want a quite simple animation: five bounces and stay on the ground with the sixth. That one I have achieved so far. But for the five bounces I want to decrease the distance of bounce by 20% of the initial distance. Say the distance is 100, it should bounce to 80 first then to 60... to 20 to 0.

You can see my attempts [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sfiddle/2EKCX/1/).

Or just the js code here:

```
$(function() {

    var time = 500;
    var bounces = 5;

    function bounceDown(){
      $(".ball").animate({top: 200}, time, function(){
        bounceUp();
      });
    };

    function bounceUp() {
      $(".ball").animate({top: 100}, time);
    };

    function shadowUp(){
      $(".shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 10, left: 85, top: 245, opacity: 1}, time,    
    function(){
        shadowDown();
      });
    };

    function shadowDown() {
      $(".shadow").animate({width: 0, height: 0, left: 130, top: 225, opacity: 0}, time);
    };     

    function finalDown(){
        $(".ball").animate({top: 200}, time);
    };

    function finalShadow(){
        $(".shadow").animate({width: 100, height: 10, left: 85, top: 245, opacity: 1}, time);    
    };

    $(".button").on("click", function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < bounces; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
          bounceDown();
          shadowUp();      
        }, time*2*i);
        setTimeout(function(){
          finalDown();
          finalShadow();
      }, 5000);
      };               
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can declare your initial `top_bounce` value:

```
var top_bounce = 100;
```

And then change your `bounceUp` function to:

```
function bounceUp() {
  $(".ball").animate({top: top_bounce}, time);
    top_bounce = top_bounce + 20;
};
```

Like you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/5wASf/

And about the "bonus question" mentioned in your comment, it'd be something similar, declare a variable like: `var shadow_size = 0;` and then your function like:

```
function shadowDown() {
        console.log(shadow_size);
      $(".shadow").animate({width: shadow_size*100, height: shadow_size*10, left: 110, top: 225, opacity:  0}, time);
        shadow_size += 0.2;

    };
```

You can see the fiddle updated, also you'd just have to do something similar with `left` to make it look centered

Comment: Thats great! But I dont get it. You just set a new variable with 100! Yu used that to indicate how far up the ball should bounce (=100). Why would adding + 20 go first to 180, 160 ... to 120 eventually? I would assume going to 120 only.

Thank you anyway. Maybe as bonus question. How could I equally handle the shadow that it does not disappear completly as the ball bounce height decreases but rather like width/height: 0/0 first bounce, 20/2 second bounce, .... 80/8 forth bounce and so on up to 100/10 with the final one. Thanks

Comment: Well from reading your question I assumed you wanted the ball to bounce up less each time, so in this case it's a matter of perspective, considering the initial `top` to be 100, the next time it'll be 120, so that means when your ball goes up then it'll be farther from the top of the screen, and so on the last iteration, `top` should be **180**, showing the ball the farthest from the top of the screen and giving the illusion of bouncing just a little bit...

Comment: @user2132380 I just updated the answer, by the way please remember to accept my answer if you found it helpful...

Comment: Hi darkajax, thanks for the answers. You are absolutly right, top should be 180 decreasing to 160, 140, etc. ... I made a mistake in that description. That was exatly what I was looking for, still I do not understand the concept behind but I guess thats my beer :-) BTW that was my first use of stackoverflow and I am impressed.