# Changing value greater than or less than the given value, doesn't work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all this isn't a new question — I'm just referencing another question which was asked already on Stack Overflow:

[Bouncing ball 5 times jquery/javascript beginners level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205466/bouncing-ball-5-times-jquery-javascript-beginners-level)

In that question, the animation was working fine for bounces 5 times, but when I try with more than 5 or less than 5, doesn't seem to properly work.

In case of emergency here is the snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  var time = 500;
  var bounces = 8;
  var top_bounce = 20;

  function bounceDown() {
    $("#ball").animate({
      left: 10,
      top: 100
    }, time, function() {
      bounceUp();
    });
  };

  function bounceUp() {
    $("#ball").animate({
      top: top_bounce
    }, time);
    top_bounce = top_bounce + 20;
  };

  function shadowUp() {
    $("#shadow").animate({
        width: 100,
        height: 5,
        left: 10,
        top: 200,
        opacity: 1
      }, time,
      function() {
        shadowDown();
      });
  };

  function shadowDown() {
    $("#shadow").animate({
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      left: 15,
      top: 200,
      opacity: 0
    }, time);
  };

  function finalDown() {
    $("#ball").animate({
      left: 10,
      top: 100
    }, time);
  };

  function finalShadow() {
    $("#shadow").animate({
      width: 100,
      height: 5,
      left: 10,
      top: 200,
      opacity: 1
    }, time);
  };

  $('#Get').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bounces; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        bounceDown();
        shadowUp();
      }, time * 2 * i);
      setTimeout(function() {
        finalDown();
        finalShadow();
      }, 5000);
    };
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
}
#ball {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e65454;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(91, 91, 91, 1) 0%, rgba(142, 142, 142, 0.84) 16%, rgba(227, 228, 229, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#5b5b5b', endColorstr='#00e3e4e5', GradientType=1);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Get">Set</button>

<div id="container">
  <div id="ball"></div>
  <div id="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: showing code that works doesn't help sort out your problem...show what's not working...are there any errors thrown?

Comment: i updated the script.. if you can see, that i changed bounce from 5 to 8.. until 5 bouces it works fine. on the sixth bounce it stays on the floor, but after few seconds, precisly after 5 seconds, the remaining three bounces starts and this time, it exceeds the top value which is declared on final down..! same as 8 bounce, if i give 4,it works fine until 4 but at the final drop, it stays above the finalDown top declaration, which is 100. if you change bounce values, you will see the problem..

Comment: need to do some math instead of using some of those hard coded values. Original worked based on 100px total...and then used increments of 20 on 5 bounces. So now try calculating increments based on total bounces vs distance

Comment: similar for other hard code values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

1. Increase `bounces`
2. Decrease `top_bounce` so the ball won't stick to the bottom too fast
3. Increase the time in `setTimeout` so the ball will have time to complete the bounces

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/monajufase/edit?js,output)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for answering the question. With your help, i made some changes. as you can see in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/emjimadhu/pen/pEaxaz?editors=0010) that i tried to place top position using bounces function. for 20, it works fine. but if i change to other vlues like above 20 or less than 20, the show is going up. can you help me to fix this? so that shadow will remain same for all values?